# Помогите правильно написать текст письма

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Настоящим письмом сообщаем список эксклюзивных рисунков ООО ИТТ". Можно ли так написать предложение?

Comment: Не по теме. Сочетание таких слов, как Список и Рисунок, не первостатейных синонимов, но слов одного порядка, хорошо было бы не употреблять, заменив, к примеру, на «Перечень рисунков» или подобное.

Answer (score 1):

*"Сообщаем список"* - неудачно.
Если вас смущает именно это, то здесь лучше *"пересылаем", "передаем", "предоставляем", "направляем"* - по обстоятельствам.

Остальное комментировать очень сложно.
Во-первых, потому, что непонятно, что за список там и ради чего его пересылают.
А во-вторых, обороты в письмах поднаторевших бюрократов всегда зависят от отношений адресата и адресанта.
Сравните, *"Ставлю Вас в известность", "Обращаю Ваше внимание", "Довожу до Вашего сведения", "Сообщаю Вам", "Информирую вас о том"* и т. п. - эти вещи в высоком канцелярском стиле совсем не взаимозаменяемы, их использование зависит он разницы в "вертикальном" и "горизонтальном" административном положении участников переписки.

В вашем случае скорее всего подошел бы вариант "Передаю для ознакомления", но это если сей список не был запрошен адресатом.

Короче, если нет иных соображений, то нейтральный вариант будет таким: 
***"Настоящим письмом направляем вам список эксклюзивных рисунков ООО ИТТ".***

Выбор между *"направляю Вам", "направляю вам","направляем Вам"* и "*направляем вам"* - это отдельный вопрос, если письмо подписывает руководитель предприятия и руководитель же указан адресатом, то *"направляю Вам"*. В переписке клерков чаще *"направляем вам"*.